# Problems with Angular and Jade, my data not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I'm using the following code to get data from Twitch api. I want the usernames, profile pic and streaming status. So far I'm getting the data from api, however, I seem not able to display it using Jade.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $scope.getdata.push([username, data, false]);
            count--;
            if (count === 0) {
              $scope.getdata = $scope.getdata.sort();
            }
          });
        } else {
          $scope.getdata.push([username, data, true]);
          count--;
          if (count === 0) {
            $scope.getdata = $scope.getdata.sort();
          }
       angular.forEach($scope.getdata,function(value,index){
                $scope.name = value[0];
         console.log($scope.name);
            })

        }
    })
```

html(Jade):

```
main(ng-app='heyTwitch')
  section(ng-controller='MainCtrl')
    header
      ul#mainMenu
        li(data-display='getdata').activeMenu All
          {{name}}


        li
        .show-data(ng-repeat="user in getdata")
          .name {{name}}
```

What is wrong with my [code](http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/EjONEe) that my data is not displaying?